# Problem with react memo in lists and thier styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning to use react memo, I am applying it to a simple task application, my problem is that I do not know how to make the styles of the items in the list work well

[image: Image from Gyazo]

As you can see when completing a task, I don't know how to update the styles of the other items in the list so that it is one in white and one in black.

TaskItem.jsx

```
import React, { memo } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import store from "../../redux/store";

//STYLES

const DIV = styled.div`

    max-height: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0px" : "50px"
    };

    opacity: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0": "1"
    };

    padding: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.done ? "0px":"12px 15px"
    };

    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, max-height 0.5s, padding 0.5s;
`;

const TR = styled.tr`
    background-color: ${
        (props) => {

            //show completed and not completed tasks
            if(useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show)){
                return props.index % 2 === 0 ? '#f3f3f3': 'none'
            }

            const tasksNotDone = props.tasks.filter((task) => !task.done)
            const index = tasksNotDone.findIndex(t => t.id === props.task.id)
            return index % 2 === 0 ? '#f3f3f3': 'none'

        }
    };

    /* 
    &:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC};
    &:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}; 
    */

    border-bottom: ${
        props => !useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks.show) && props.task.done ? "none": "1px solid #dddddd"
    };;

    transition: visibility 0.5s;

    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #009879;
    }
`;


function TaskRow({ task, toggleDoneTask, index, tasks }) {

    return (
        
        <TR task={task} tasks={tasks} index={index}>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {console.log('render', task)}
                    {task.title}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV done={task.done}>
                    {task.description}
                </DIV>
            </td>
            <td>
                <DIV  done={task.done}>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        checked={task.done}
                        onChange={toggleDoneTask}
                        style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    />
                </DIV>
            </td>
        </TR>
    )
}


export default memo(TaskRow, (prev, next) => {
    // store.getState().toggleDoneTasks.show

    //COMPARE TASK OBJECT
    const prevTaskKeys = Object.keys(prev.task);
    const nextTaskKeys = Object.keys(next.task);

    const sameLength = prevTaskKeys.length === nextTaskKeys.length;
    const sameEntries = prevTaskKeys.every(key => {
        return nextTaskKeys.includes(key) && prev.task[key] === next.task[key];
    });

    return sameLength && sameEntries;
})
```

Tasks.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import TaskItem from "./TaskItem";

function saveLocalStorage(tasks) {
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

function TasksReducer(taskItems, { type, task }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "UPDATE_TAKS": {
      let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems].map((task) => ({ ...task }));
      let newItems = taskItemsCopy.map((t) => {
        if (t.id === task.id) {
          t.done = !t.done;
        }
        return t;
      });
      saveLocalStorage(newItems);
      return newItems;
    }

    case "ADD_TASK": {
      const newItems = [...taskItems, task];
      saveLocalStorage(newItems);
      return newItems;
    }

    default:
      window.alert("INVALID ACTION");
      break;
  }
}

const initialState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];

//STYLES

const styleTable = {
  borderCollapse: "collapse",
  margin: "25px 0",
  fontSize: "0.9em",
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  minWidth: "400px",
  boxShadow: "0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)"
};

const styleTr = {
  backgroundColor: "#009879",
  color: "#ffffff",
  textAlign: "left"
};

const styleTh = {
  padding: "12px 15px"
};

function Tasks({ newTask, show }) {
  const [taskItems, dispatch] = useReducer(TasksReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!newTask) return;
    newTaskHandler({ id: taskItems.length + 1, ...newTask });
  }, [newTask]);

  const newTaskHandler = (task) => {
    dispatch({ type: "ADD_TASK", task });
  };

  const toggleDoneTask = (task) => {
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_TAKS", task });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>learning react </h1>
      <table style={styleTable}>
        <thead>
          <tr style={styleTr}>
            <th style={styleTh}>Title</th>
            <th style={styleTh}>Description</th>
            <th style={styleTh}>Done</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {taskItems.map(
            (task, i) =>
              (show || !task.done) && (
                <TaskItem
                  tasks={taskItems}
                  index={i}
                  task={task}
                  key={task.id}
                  show={show}
                  toggleDoneTask={() => toggleDoneTask(task)}
                />
              )
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Tasks;
```

If you need the complete code:
[image: Edit inspiring-sea-hp9kt]

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug in your code, in the component TaskItem.js, the memo doesn't update when tasks change. It is only changed when you click an item. You can remove the memo function to check or update the function memo when tasks updated

Follow my link
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ganguly-u92i7)

My code updated file TaskItem.js

```
  const sameDone = prev.tasks.some(
    (t, index) => t.done !== prev.tasks[index].done
  );

  return sameLength && sameEntries && sameDone;
```

Comment: Great job, but please paste the updated code here for future reference. Links tend to go dead over time.

Comment: If it works, but you break the memorization, marking a task as completed renders all the others (look at the console)

Comment: I have an idea for it, you can use redux to get all list to find tasksNotDone in styled

Comment: I don't understand what redux would solve

Comment: I can see you used redux in your code, it's toggleDoneTasks. You will create a list of tasks in redux, and call it the same is useSelector((state)=> state.toggleDoneTasks). It will rerender in there, it's good for performance